# Can FFMPEG read SPC format on Windows?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I saw in [some questions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896196/spc-to-wav-command-line) that ffmpeg could convert SPC audio format (basically chiptune extracted from Super Nintendo) into more common formats like WAV or MP3, but I tried to do [this command](https://smwc.me/1443164): `ffmpeg -t 120 -i input.spc output.wav` in my ffmpeg on windows 10 but i got this error: `input.spc: Invalid data found when processing input`.

This SPC file is playable in Winamp with Chipamp plugin, so is it a problem with my ffmpeg instance?

I've downloaded my ffmpeg from Zeranoe's build server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg relies on an external library (Game Music Emu) to read SPC files. Zeranoe's builds dropped that library recently, so you will need an older build from Sep 2017 or earlier - http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win64/static/

Comment: Thanks. A little off-topic question: is there any tutorial to compile myself ffmpeg with this library? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For Windows? Use https://github.com/jb-alvarado/media-autobuild_suite . Disable all libs you don't want.